# Is This Gonna Be Another Rebus?

Tags: rebus

Gonna Try another Rebus puzzle just for fun

1.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

2.

[image]

[image]

[image]

3.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I have all three:

1:

> **GOLDEN**, from GOAL - A + DEN.

2:

> **IMPLIED**, from IMP + LIED

3:

> **NEIGHBO(U)RS**, (sorry, am Canadian) from NEIGH + BORS

Comment: Correct Answer. Was it too easy?? :) @El-Guest

Comment: So what's the meaning of this? Just three random words?

Comment: Clearly, you live in the middle of nowhere with no one else surrounding you. But, when you talk about your living situation, you always say that if you _did_ have people living next to you, they'd be pretty freaking great. [Diddily.](https://tenor.com/view/ned-flanders-hi-the-simpsons-diddly-ho-neighborino-gif-9275724)

Comment: Nope just random words. Are those words supposed to have some kind of meaning in a rebus puzzle? @DanielP

Comment: @KevinL not necessarily -- since you've separated them into 1, 2, and 3 they can be any words you want. If they were all one puzzle (no separation), I'd have expected some sort of meaning or phrase to come out of the combination of words.

Comment: @El-Guest I see. Thx for the explanation :)

Answer (score 2):

1.

> Gol den

2.
???

3.

> Neigh bors

Comment: Can u combine those words into one. @Chris Cudmore